# CASE Statement SQL handle data issue

Tags: sql, sql-server, case

I am trying to create a calculation to handle a tricky data issue.

I need to measure when a transaction is run for an account when the date of birth field is being populated.

Sometimes in the data, an account can have 2 people on it, and if the date of birth is populated for only one of the persons, and the timestamp is the same, then this counts as a transaction with date of birth populated. I don't want to count the second row in this instance which has a blank value for date of birth.

I have been playing around with using a Y/N flag or a 0/1 Count in the case statement, but I have not figured out how to handle this second blank row.

This is the basic `CASE` statement I have been using:

```
SELECT DISTINCT
    [Account_Nbr],
    [Timestmp],
    CASE 
       WHEN [DOB] <> '   ' THEN 'Y' 
       ELSE 'N' 
    END AS 'DOB ORDERED'
FROM 
    TABLE
GROUP BY
    [Account_Nbr], [Timestmp], [DOB]
```

Sample data is below - I would want to mark this as a transaction that has processed with DOB populated, but i don't want the blank DOB to be counted or flagged as N

[image]

Any ideas on how to handle this? Thanks

Comment: Most people here want sample table data _and the expected result_ as formatted text, not as images.

Comment: BTW, that's a case _expression_ (it returns a value.) A case _statement_ can be used in stored procedures to do conditional execution of code.)

Comment: Can you add your desired output ?

Comment: What is the data type of DOB?  The comparison of a date to a string doesn't make sense.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understod correctly this is a possible soultion for returning only one row from a account_nbr that has multiple records

```
-- Just inserting sample data here.
WITH CTE AS (
SELECT Account_Nbr = 123, Timestmp = GETDATE() , Operator =  1, DOB = '19700101'
UNION ALL
SELECT Account_Nbr = 123, Timestmp = GETDATE() , Operator =  2, DOB = '   ')

--No distinct necessary since it will always group by account_nbr and timestamp.
SELECT  Account_Nbr,
        Timestmp,
        DOB_Ordered = (CASE WHEN MAX(DOB) <> '   '  THEN 'Y' ELSE 'N' END)
FROM CTE
GROUP BY
    [Account_Nbr], [Timestmp]
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions! I appreciate it, i'll play about with these and see where i get!

Answer (score 0):

I think you want aggregation with a `CASE` expression:

```
SELECT Account_Nbr, Timestmp,
       (CASE WHEN COUNT(*) = COUNT(DOB) THEN 'Y' ELSE 'N'
        END) as missing_dob_flag
FROM TABLE
GROUP BY [Account_Nbr], [Timestmp]
```

It is reasonable to assume that a column called `DOB` (date of birth) is stored as a date.  Dates should be stored as a date in the database.  If this is not the case, you should fix the data model.

If you are stuck with someone else's really bad decisions about data types, you can use `TRY_CONVERT()`:

```
SELECT Account_Nbr, Timestmp,
       (CASE WHEN COUNT(*) = COUNT(TRY_CONVERT(DATE, DOB)) THEN 'Y' ELSE 'N'
        END) as missing_dob_flag
FROM TABLE
GROUP BY [Account_Nbr], [Timestmp];
```

Note that the conversion may require a format argument.

Comment: This will always return Y since he's not using NULL value in DOB column apparently

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions! I appreciate it, i'll play about with these and see where i get!